# NHinerbate Query problem - Join Query with Non - primarykeys

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am new to Nhibernate, I'm trying to use nhibernate in a project and i wanted to convert the following sql query to Nhibernate HQL? Is this query possible in Nhibernate HQL/ ICriteria?

```
SELECT     dbo.Table1.*
FROM         dbo.Table1 INNER JOIN
             dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table1.Id2 = Table2.Id INNER JOIN
            dbo.Table2 AS T2 ON dbo.Table1.Id3 = T2.Id
```

this is what I tried and failed.I am getting an exception **Path expected for join!**

```
[from Table1 T1 inner join Table2 T2 inner join Table2 T3 where T1.Id2 = T2.Id and
          T1.Id3 = T3.Id]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1: Adding classes that I'm using.

```
 public class Table1
{
  public virtual long Id {get;set;}
  public virtual Guid Id2 {get;set}
  public virtual Guid Id3 {get;set}

  other properties ....
}

public class Table2
{
  public virtual long primaryKey {get;set;}
  public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}

  other properties ....
}
```

I didn't use instance of class Table2 in the Table1 class.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What is "a" and "e" in your HQL query?

Comment: well that was mistake (it was from my production code ,it has been removed now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Stefan, finally I am able to solve this problem.

I'll try to emulate the problem using a different example.Hope this one could be useful to some one else.

Problem : say I have a two tables Employee and Project,the project table have two columns 'Lead' and 'Manager' which will store the Employee code.I had to get the project details based on employee code of Manager and Lead.

Here is the solution for my problem.
**Employee mapping file.**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
       namespace="Learn.Models" assembly="Learn.Models">
  <class name="Employee" table="Employee">
    <id column="Id" type="Int64">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="EntityId" column="EmployeeEntityId" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="LastName" column="LastName" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="DateOfBirth" column="DateOfBirth" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="EmpCode" column="EmpCode" not-null="true"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Project mapping file** :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
       namespace="Learn.Models" assembly="Learn.Models">
  <class name="Project" table="Project">
    <id column="Id" type="Int64">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="EntityId" column="ProjectEntityId" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="ProjectName" column="ProjName" not-null="true"></property>

    <many-to-one name="ProjectManager" class="Employee" property-ref="EmpCode" column="Manager" lazy="proxy"></many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="ProjectLead" class="Employee" property-ref="EmpCode" column="Lead" lazy="proxy"></many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Employee Class** :

```
public class Employee : IEntity
{
    public Employee()
    {
    }

    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid EntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmpCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Project Class**:

```
public class Project:IEntity
{
    public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee ProjectLead { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee ProjectManager { get; set; }

    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid EntityId { get; set; }

}
```

I had to get the  project details based on employee code of 'ProjectLead' and 'ProjectManager',and this is the HQL query I used.

```
string hql = "select p from Project p "
                + "join p.ProjectLead as lead "
                + "join p.ProjectManager as manager "
                + "where p.ProjectLead.EmpCode = 006 and "
                + "p.ProjectManager.EmpCode = 005";
```

Answer (score 3):

In HQL, you don't join "tables". You start the query on the first class and navigate to properties.

for instance:

```
class A
{
  B MyB { get; set; }
}

class B
{
}
```

Hql:

```
SELECT a FROM A a join MyB
```

MyB is a property name.

To show you the actual query for your case, I need to know the classes you want to write the query for.

It may look something like this:

```
SELECT t1
FROM T1 t1
   join MyT2 t2
```

---

**Edit**:

The query to your classes would look like this:

```
SELECT t1
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.Id2 = t2.Id
```

There is no join, because there is no relation in the model. You can only join it by cross product and where clause.

You don't benefit much from NH when you don't work with a useful class model. Useful means that you can navigate through the model without accessing the database all the time. When you just write classes which look like database tables, you won't benefit much.

Your classes could look like this:

```
public class Class1
{
  public virtual long Id {get;set;}
  public virtual Class2 Class2 {get;set}

  other properties ....
}

public class Class2
{
  public virtual long primaryKey {get;set;}
  public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}

  other properties ....
}
```

Then you map it as `many-to-one` using `property-ref` to specify a link to a non-primary key.

Comment: Hi Stefan , thanks for the reply. I have added the a sample model of the classes that i have used.

Comment: Is it necessary that we need to have a instance of Class B in Class A even though there is no physical relationship between Table A and Table B?

Comment: Even if a constrained FK does not exist you would still have to map the property Id2 to the class Table2 instead of the Guid you present in your mapping. The idea behind NH is the only thing you know is the domain and in HQL you expressively traverse the graph and NH translates that to actual SQL. So if property Id2 of Table1 represents the Id of Table2 and you want to traverse Table2 in your domain, you will have to map that property as an object of type Table2

Comment: @wizzardz: I add another section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If you can see my Sql query,Id of the Table 2 refers to Id2 and Id3 in Table1.So in model class Class1 do I need to add another property say for example public virtual Class2 ObjId3 {get;set} to get the hql query correct?